# Text in Chrome showing up as garbled mojibake?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

Today (May 25, 2023) in an existing Chrome session, all text on every site I checked started showing up as grabled [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

This persisted even after restarting Chrome and an update installing. For instance, here's a screenshot of how `chrome://whats-new/` displays for me in Chrome Version 113.0.5672.127 (Official Build) (64-bit):

[image: mojibake]

I noticed that with some pages (Amazon.com, for instance) the text would initially display correctly, then it would switch to mojibake after the page loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the true root cause, but I was able to mitigate the problem by disabling the [Font blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/font-blocker/knpgaobajhnhgkhhoopjepghknapnikl) 1.19 extension that I have had installed for a long time to block [downloadable web fonts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Web_fonts).  Clicking its [image: Font blocker extension icon] icon would temporarily fix the page I was viewing. Turning it off completely fixed the problem generally. Here's the text from my question with the extension disabled:

[image]

I don't think the problem is due to this extension itself, because it hasn't been updated since 2019 and I've been using it for years with no problem.